# cloud platform project dialog box

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm doing the basic tutorial for google Quickstart bot in section to part 2 I see:

2) In the Cloud Platform project dialog box, click the URL for the project associated with the script.

I don't see any urls to click. Image of dialog box below
[image]

Comment: What "basic tutorial for google Quickstart bot"? Are you sure that you didn't missed any step?

Answer (score 0):

That's because since the [release of April, 8th](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_8_2019) you can no longer view the default GCP assigned to your project (that is, if you created the project after the release). If properly [reassigned a standard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) GCP, the link will appear in the dialog box in place of the *This script has an Apps Script managed Cloud Platform project* placeholder.

Please, read this official guide on how to [switch to standard GCP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) (if you don't have a standard GCP yet, there is a [guide on how to create one](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project) - btw, it might be confusing, but the button is clickable and will lead you straight to cloud console) and follow the steps provided.

Once done, copy the GCP number, open the resource manager again, paste the number and click on the "Set Project" button. If everything is configured correctly, you will see something like this and be able to access your new GCP:

[image]